# Get the MongoID back after an insert using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, insert

I am using `PHP` and the official Mongo driver and doing an insert.

```
$collection->insert($data_object);
```

Then doing:

```
$data_object_id = $data_object['_id'];
```

Which if I do:

```
print_r($data_object_id);
```

Looks right:

```
 MongoId Object
 (
     [$id] => 521d982298a618b9798b456b
 )
```

However, when trying to do:

```
 echo "Inserted: " . $data_object_id->__toString() . "...";
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Comment: See [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/mongoid.tostring.php). You don't need to directly call `__toString()`

Comment: When I do just `$data_object_id`, I get: `Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: This works for me, I am unsure what is wrong for you

Comment: Hi Justin. Can one of the answers below be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing it in the following way

```
$IDm = new MongoId();

$data_object = array(
  '_id' => $IDm,
  ...    // all other things that you need
) 

$collection->insert($data_object);
```

and later you can do something like echo `$IDm->{'$id'}` to give you ID as a string

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason that `$data_object_id` should be an instance of stdClass by the time you're invoking `__toString()`, unless there is some code you're not sharing in the original post. It would be more helpful if you pasted an entire script reproducing your problem, instead of single lines with discussion between them.

You wrote:

> ```
> echo "Inserted: " . $data_object_id->__toString() . "...";`
> ```
>
> I am getting the following error:
>
> ```
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`
> ```

If `$data_object_id` is a stdClass instance, that `echo` line would result in the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::__toString()
```

You should be able to diagnose this simply by inspecting the [type](http://php.net/gettype)/[class](http://php.net/get_class) of `$data_object_id` or checking if the `__toString()` [method exists](http://php.net/method_exists) on it.

Consider the following script:

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient();
$c = $m->test->foo;

$doc = (object) ['x' => 1];
$c->insert($doc);
printf("Document is: %s\n", get_class($doc));
printf("_id field is: %s\n", get_class($doc->_id));
printf("_id cast to string: %s\n", (string) $doc->_id);
printf("_id toString(): %s\n", $doc->_id->__toString());

echo "\n";

$doc = ['x' => 2];
$c->insert($doc);
printf("Document is: %s\n", gettype($doc));
printf("_id field is: %s\n", get_class($doc['_id']));
printf("_id cast to string: %s\n", (string) $doc['_id']);
printf("_id toString(): %s\n", $doc['_id']->__toString());
```

This inserts a single-field document, testing both object and array forms, and prints information about the `_id` field/property that gets set on the argument after the call to `insert()`. This should yield the following output (the ObjectId hashes will differ, of course):

```
Document is: stdClass
_id field is: MongoId
_id cast to string: 5220ad40e84df1b667000000
_id toString(): 5220ad40e84df1b667000000

Document is: array
_id field is: MongoId
_id cast to string: 5220ad40e84df1b667000001
_id toString(): 5220ad40e84df1b667000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by casting the MongoId Object?

```
$data_object_id = (string) $data_object['_id'];
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: And with `$data_object['_id']->{'$id'}` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data= iterator_to_array($data_object_id);
 print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

create variable with new mongoId() and push this to your object

```
$id = new MongoId();
$data_object = array(
 "_id"       => $id,
 "moreData" => "someData"
);
try {
    $collection->insert($data_object);
    return $id;
} catch(MongoException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

to echo the id string do

```
echo $id->{'$id'}
```